# How to redirect routes (with wildcards) but go to a default if redirect not found?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I need to redirect `/author/john` to `/about/john`. Here's my code:

```
  get "/author/:name", to: redirect("/about/%{name}")
```

The problem is, not all the names attached to `author` have an equivalent in `about`. E.g. maybe there's a `/author/mary` but there's not a `/about/mary`.

With my current code, typing in `/author/mary` will redirect to `/about/mary`, which then pulls up a 404 error.

**Question**

Is it possible to have a redirect route (like above), that defaults to a url (e.g. default is simply `/about`) if the redirected url fails to find anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question "no". Unless, you write a code that queries your DB to check that a record exists (I am presuming "Mary" and others are coming from database table).

However you can do that in your controller. Instead of using `.find()` method, that throws an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error, that then causes to return 404 error, use `find_by_id()` or `where()` and redirect if a record not found.